# Get last modification timestamp of a file using ADB

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to access the last modified time of a file on an Android device using ADB, without installing anything on the device? `adb shell ls -l <path>` gives only minute precision, and `adb`'s version of `ls` doesn't have `--time-style` (at least in the current latest version). `pull -a` preserves the timestamp, but the reason I want the timestamp in the first place is to check whether it needs to be pulled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stat` utility to get information about a file.

Run this from the terminal and replace `PATH_TO_FILE` the the absolute path of the file on the device/emulator that you are trying to get the last modified time for. It should print it to the console.

```
adb shell stat -c %y PATH_TO_FILE
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's guarantee to be available starting with some Android version (which?) or some devices have it and others don't?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I do not know but stat is part of GNU Core Utilities so I imagine it is likely to be available in everything.

Comment: There are certainly Android devices without even `cp` (since I've seen multiple questions asking why it doesn't work) :)